# « Par tâtonnement » ou « par essais et erreurs » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, usage, science

> Ils ont procédé par essais et erreurs pour trouver une solution.
>
> Ils ont procédé par tâtonnement pour trouver une solution.

Y a-t-il une différence entre les deux phrases ? Peut-on employer **par essais et erreurs** et **par tâtonnement** de façon interchangeable ? Lequel est plus courant/compréhensible ? Lequel est plus adéquat dans un contexte scientifique ?
Parmi les deux phrases, laquelle interprète de façon plus idiomatique la phrase anglaise:

> They proceeded **by trial and error** to find a solution.

Comment: En général on n'emploie ni « versus », ni « contre » en français ; « ou » est la conjonction la plus habituelle dans les titres lorsqu'il y a un choix à faire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D'après Google ngrams, ***par essais et erreurs*** existe en français depuis une centaine d'année (1920). Cette expression est très vraisemblablement née d'un calque de l'anglais ***by trial and error*** que l'on rencontre dès 1713. Elle semble aujourd'hui bien établie mais je ne peux m'empêcher de lui trouver un air d'anglicisme.

*Par tâtonnement* est une expression beaucoup plus ancienne mais qui n'est pas associée à l'approche scientifique. Elle n'est donc peut-être pas très recommandée dans le contexte de la question.

Si l'on souhaite éviter *essai et erreur*, on peut envisager une troisième solution : l'adverbe *empiriquement* ou *de manière/façon empirique* qui ont la même signification :

> Ils ont procédé **empiriquement** pour trouver une solution.

Comment: Il me semble que la science peut procéder par tâtonnement à un certain moment, par exemple quand peu de données sont disponibles et qu’on n’a pas commencé à cerner même la nature de certains paramètres, ou alors quand le temps et/ou les moyens financiers sont limités et que l’on ajuste quelques paramètres en tentant d'évaluer grossièrement, à la lumière de connaissances imparfaites et lacunaires, ce qui fonctionnera le mieux, sans pouvoir trouver prétendre pouvoir trouver la solution optimale du premier coup.

Comment: @Montéedelait J'ai tempéré ma phrase mais j'ai la sensation qu'empiriquement et *essais et erreurs* indiquent que les essais successifs suivent une certaine logique pour tenter de s'approcher de la solution tandis que tâtonnement s'appuie plus sur le hasard, mais la différence, si elle existe, est ténue.

Comment: Je dirais plutôt **de façon empirique** : je n'ai pas le souvenir d'avoir rencontré *empiriquement* au fil de mes lectures.

Comment: @dralpuop J'ai ajouté ta suggestion. Google Ngrams trouve beaucoup d'occurences de "procédé empiriquement".

Answer (score 1):

Oui, il y a une différence et elle est de nature technique; « par essai et erreur » implique une plus grande systématique et il est préférable de l'employer pour des questions scientifiques comme par exemple déterminer les racines d'une équation ou déterminer des coefficients relatifs à des matériaux en physique. « Par tâtonnement » évoque un peu la recherche d'un interrupteur dans le noir et parfois les « corrections » que l'on peut apporter dans un tel processus ne sont en réalité que des actions qui empirent le degré de proximité, desquelles on n'apprend rien.

En science la phrase anglaise ne devrait être interprétée que par « par essais et erreurs », sauf peut être en d'assez rares cas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99386/discussion-on-answer-by-lph--par-tatonnement--ou--par-essais-et-erreurs-).

Comment: @Evpok There is no matter of extended discussion but the problem of the resolution of an assertion made in the answer, which moreover  is probably costing me a downvote and is sure to  cost me one if the comment in which the allegation are made were  left without reply.

Comment: If you feel the need to answer with 4 full-length comments, then yes, that's an extended discussion. If you *really* feel like complaining about it, do it in the aforementioned chat.